# Create a list of files in current file for use later in code

Tags: excel, vba, directory

I have a file that is referencing 3 files outside of it. The problem is the outside files will have their version number changed when there is a change.

code is currently written to pull from C:documents/product_eval

01-Main_v1 is the main file that pulls
02-Address_v1
03_Products_v1

However, we now have a v2 for each of these files. I need a way to have file_03 always pull the 3rd file in the list of files, no matter what the version.

I feel like listing the code I tried will just confuse people, as it is so far off.

but here is the coding it will be feeding into

```
Sub LaunchBatching3_00(sourcePath As String, exportFolder As String, activeName As String)
    Dim Adrs_PATH As String
    Dim Prod_PATH As String
    Adrs_PATH = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\02-Address_v1.xlms"
    Prod_PATH = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\03-Products_v1.xlms"
```

Comment: will the old files in the folder be deleted when a newer version is saved in that folder? you could work with INSTR-function then to determine the file and if INSTR result is >0 you take that file.

Comment: Old files will be moved to another folder called Archive

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim sFiles as Object, fFiles as Variant ,ppath as String,  count as Long, 
Set fFiles=CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
set sFiles =fFiles.GetFolder(ppath)'get the folder object from folder path(variable ppath)
count=0
For Each x in sFiles.Files'loops all files in folder search for the last version by filename
If InStr(1,x.Name,"_v")>0 then
If CLng(Mid(x.Name,InStr(1,x.Name,"_v")+2,1))>count then count=CLng(Mid(x.Name,InStr(1,x.Name,"_v")+2,1))'gets the largest version
End If
Next x

For Each x in sFiles.Files
If CLng(Mid(x.Name,InStr(1,x.Name,"_v")+2,1)=If CLng(Mid(x.Name,InStr(1,x.Name,"_v")+2,1)=count then 
'... fill your actions, for example, 
Workbooks.Open FileName:=x.Name
End if 
Next x
```